# Use MacBook Air as standalone Display

Tags: macbook-pro

Is it possible to use MacBook Air as a display by connecting the peripheral via Thunderbolt 2 port ? I can get an adaptor if required. I would like to use my MacBook air as a display for Play Station 4.

Comment: Is this because you want to stream it so others can watch or do you want to play the game using the MBA's display as a monitor?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not natively possible to use your MacBook Air as a standalone display.

Comment: That is to say, not natively. Third-party software is available to stuff like this, but it's subpar compared to having a second display via HDMI or DisplayPort.